# Node AWS Lambda in private subnet not able to return callback

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

**Following is my problem statement -**
1. I have a Regional API Gateway endpoint

2. There is a Lambda function in a VPC Private subnet getting invoked by the Lambda, to access RDS.
3. A Postman call to the API Gateway is able to invoke the Lambda function.
4. The Lambda function is able to process everything inside it properly.
5. The Lambda function code reaches the response block of the code, but is not able to return the response.
6. The Lambda function's security group has all outbound allowed via NAT Gateway in a Public subnet.

**Following is the function handler -**

```
var async = require('async');
var moment = require('moment');
var service = require('./some-service');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var requestBody = event['body-json'];

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            var processRequest = {};
            processRequest.validationMessage = validateRequest(requestBody);

            if(processRequest.validationMessage == ''){
                processRequest.isValid = true;

                service.processService(requestBody,function(err, response) {
                    if(err){
                        callback(err, null);
                    }
                    else{
                        callback(null, response);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                processRequest.isValid = false;
                callback(null, processRequest);
            }
        }
    ],
    function(err, resp) {
        let response = {};
        if (err) {
            response = {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify('API Error : ' + err),
            };
            callback(err, response);
        } 
        else {
            if(resp.isValid){
                response = {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: 'Record updated for user_id '+requestBody.user_id,
                }; 
                console.log('Success block! ', response);
                callback(null, response);   
            }
            else{
                console.log('Failure block!');
                response = {
                    statusCode: 500,
                    body: resp.validationMessage,
                }; 
                callback(null, response);
            }
        }
    });
};

function validateRequest(requestBody){
    var isValid = '';

    if(requestBody['user_id'] == undefined){
        console.log('user_id missing');
        isValid += 'user_id, ';
    }
    if(requestBody['added_by'] == undefined){
        isValid += 'added_by, ';
    }
    if(isValid != ''){
        isValid = isValid.substring(0, isValid.lastIndexOf(','));
        isValid += ' missing in the request';
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

The CloudWatch logs show the code is able to reach the Success Block,

```
Success block! { statusCode: 200, body: 'Record updated for user_id 17' }
```

**Postman response -**

```
{
    "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}
```

**What could be the issue?**

Comment: What does Postman show? Timeout, error message, something else? Does it work if you modify the response object's body, for example: body: { message: 'Record updated for user_id '+requestBody.user_id}

Comment: I created a function from scratch, with default node code, put the function into same private subnets and same SG. But this one got executed and also responded to the API Gateway. seems like a code issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by adding the following, in the first line under the handler -

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

Comment: Does some-service contain db connections? Normally with the code I can see you probably wouldn't need this.

Comment: Yes the Service layer is making DynamoDB and MySQL calls

Comment: Ahh yeah OK, so that's whats causing your issue(as I guess you've figured out) because it has open connections, remember though if the Lambda container gets re-used you can reuse that connection!